# Error en planteamiento de CTE en MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb

Tengo la siguiente consulta que hace uso de un `subquery` para obtener el monto máximo de una tabla

```
SELECT clienteNumero, orden, monto FROM pagos 
WHERE monto = (SELECT MAX(monto) FROM pagos);
```

La cual funciona y me devuelve

```
clienteNumero   orden   monto
6               235     324566
```

Sin embargo cuando trato de hacer uso de una `CTE` de este modo

```
WITH Maximo AS(
    SELECT clienteNumero, orden, MAX(monto) FROM pagos
)
SELECT * FROM Maximo;
```

Me da el monto correcto, pero el `clienteNumero y el número de orden también esta mal`

```
clienteNumero   orden   MAX(monto)
1               230      324566
```

Me ayudan por favor a identificar lo que esta claramente mal en el planteamiento?

Comment: Por cierto, ¿de qué versión de mariadb son las CTE? Estoy probando con un 10.1.31-MariaDB y no me lo reconoce, ¿hay que activar algo especial?

Comment: De hecho son funcionales desde la 10.2.1 de acuerdo a su documentación @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro, es que tienes la expresión que genera la tabla temporal mal escrita. Prueba así:

```
WITH Maximo AS(
    SELECT clienteNumero, orden, monto FROM pagos 
      WHERE monto = (SELECT MAX(monto) FROM pagos)
)
SELECT * FROM Maximo;
```

Comment: Entonces he entendido mal el concepto de las CTE pues creí que eran para ya no hacer subconsultas

Comment: Ni idea, yo acabo de descubrirlas pero, según el manual, tienen buena pinta: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: Aclarar que ese enlace es hacia MySQL y no a mariadb

Comment: La CTE con el WITH sirve para crear una especie de "VISTA" temporal, a la que puedes hacerle luego las consultas que precises, pero para crearla, tienes que condicionarla igual que cualquier SELECT

Comment: ¿Y tienen las limitaciones de las vistas o pueden incluir subconsultas?